# Get error with openPopup in leaflet react

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem with leaflet on react. I want that when I click on the card, I get popup in the place where I clicked, I wrote this code. It works in usually javascript, but throws an error in React

```
this.map.on('click', async function (e) {
            var coord = e.latlng;
            var lat = coord.lat;
            var lng = coord.lng;
            var popup = L.popup({minWidth: 30, maxHeight: 300})
                .setLatLng([50.51754, 136.94726])
                .setContent(`test`)
                .openOn(this.map);

        });
```

I get this error when clicking on a card

```
   Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'openPopup' of undefined
  104 | // @method openOn(map: Map): this
  105 | // Adds the popup to the map and closes the previous one. The same as `map.openPopup(popup)`.
  106 | openOn: function (map) {
> 107 |     map.openPopup(this);
      | ^  108 |    return this;
  109 | },
  110 |
```

Thank you!